# No activity launches

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, launcher

My application installs, atleast according to Eclipse, as it should. Then it stops with the following in the console:

```
[2011-10-17 14:10:58 - AppName] Uploading AppName.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-17 14:11:07 - AppName] Installing AppName.apk...
[2011-10-17 14:11:23 - AppName] Success!
[2011-10-17 14:11:24 - AppName] \AppName\bin\AppName.apk installed on device
[2011-10-17 14:11:24 - AppName] Done!
```

When i click the launcher icon i get a toast saying:
"Application is not installed on your phone"

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.qualifiedpath.appname"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity   
                android:name="com.qualifiedpath.appname.AppTitleScreenActivity"
                android:label="label"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:noHistory="false"
                android:launchMode="standard">
    </activity>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

    <activity
                android:name=".GameScreenActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity   
                android:name=".KeypadActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    </activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

you have put the above code `out of activity tag`.Put it `inside activity tag`.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<activity android:name="com.qualifiedpath.appname.AppTitleScreenActivity"
          android:label="label"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:noHistory="false"
          android:launchMode="standard">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Sorry, too late, second place though!

Answer (score 1):

you need to place intent filter inside the activity tag
use this code

```
 <activity   
            android:name="com.qualifiedpath.appname.AppTitleScreenActivity"
            android:label="label"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="false"
            android:launchMode="standard">
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```